# Ошибка LNK2001 при указании макроса Q_OBJECT в Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

Следует сказать, что я тщательно погуглил и перепробовал множество путей, но проблема не исчезла. Вот собственно код, все в одном файле main.cpp, по задумке при нажатии на кнопку она отделяется в новое окно.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>


class custombtn: public QPushButton{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    custombtn(QWidget * parent = nullptr):QPushButton(parent){}
public slots:
    void slotChangeParent(){
        this->setParent(nullptr);
        this->show();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QWidget wgt;
    custombtn btn(&wgt);
    QLabel lbl("LABEL",&wgt);
    btn.resize(300,300);
    lbl.resize(300,100);
    btn.show();
    lbl.show();
    wgt.show();
    QObject::connect(&btn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), &btn, SLOT(slotChangeParent()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Вот pro файл:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Я пробовал запускать qmake, создать новый проект и собирать в нем, удалять папку Debug и компилировать заново, путь к проекту состоит только из английских букв, пробовал копировать проект даже в корень диска(чтобы убедится что дело не в путях), но ошибки из серии `LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const* __cdecl custombrn::metaObject(void)const"[...]` так и остались. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Объявление в *.h вынесите... Возможно, moc не может по такому файлу сгенерить нужные сорцы. Или вы что-то не так собираете...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов собираю все как обычно - qmake - запустить в qt creator

Comment: Добавьте в конец вашего файла сгенерированный MOC файл: `#include "main.moc"`

Comment: @PavelParshin такого файла нет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо, разнес все по разным файлам и работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать макрос `Q_OBJECT` необходимо, чтобы класс, использующий его находился в отдельных файлах, в данном случае - в файлах `custombtn.h` и `custombtn.cpp`.
Файл `custombtn.h`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
class custombtn: public QPushButton{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    custombtn(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
public slots:
    void slotChangeParent();
};
```

Файл `custombtn.cpp:`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
custombtn::custombtn(QWidget * parent):QPushButton(parent){}
void custombtn::slotChangeParent(){
    this->setParent(nullptr);
    this->show();
}
```

Comment: А пруфы будут? (кроме эмпирики)

Comment: @free_ze а какие вам нужны пруфы?

Comment: Ссылки на документацию. Ни о каких таких соглашениях я не читал, но с этой проблемой тоже сталкивался.

Comment: @free_ze, Я в документации тоже подобного не читал. Сейчас целенаправленно поискал, но конкретно о том, что классы должны быть вынесены в отдельные файлы там не пишется. Но факт в том, что работает именно так.

Comment: Помнится, Шлее что-то мутное писал про ручное подключение *.moc-файла.

Comment: @free_ze, Да, вот: _Для создания moc-файла вручную
можно воспользоваться следующей командой:_
`moc -о proc.moc proc.h` А затем подключить moc файл в конце main.cpp - `#include "proc.moc"`. Но он не советует так делать.

Comment: moc не нужно вручную создавать, он автоматически создаётся, но при реализации всей программы в одном main.cpp действительно в конце файла нужно написать `#include "main.moc"`. Ну или вынести объявление класса в *.h.

Comment: @aleks.andr так речь и идет про всю реализацию в одном файле.

Comment: @free_ze По поводу документации, то вот цитата (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html): " Whenever qmake is run, it parses the project's header files and generates make rules to invoke moc for those files that contain a Q_OBJECT macro." Компилятор moc анализирует только заголовочные файлы.